# Keeping selected item from dropdown box after page refresh in asp web form

Tags: c#, asp.net, dropdownbox

I have a `aspx` page that has several `drop down list`. So when the users forget to input some values i have to show an error to user, but every `DDL` are initialized again, and the users information are lost, how can I avoid this ?

When the users forget to input values i return them to current `url`

```
url1=www.spadsystem.com
Response.Redirect(Url1);
```

I heard that we can avoid this problem by using something like `absolute` i am not sure.

Comment: Use Session object to store the SelectedIndex property of ComboBox, then apply it in Page_Load() event. Rgds,

Comment: i have 30 DDL ins my page,how can i store their states using session?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use SessionState object to store the SelectedIndex property of ComboBox (e.g. Cmb), then apply it in Page_Load() event.

Example 1: Store value in Session

```
int _idx = Cmb.SelectedIndex;
Session["idx"] = _idx.ToString();
```

Example 2: Read from Session and apply to ComboBox:

```
if(!IsPostBack) {
     Cmb.SelectedIndex = (int)(Session["idx"]);
}
```

More details at: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ms178581%28v=vs.100%29.aspx

Rgds,

Answer (score 0):

Avoid redirecting to another page and back to show the error, and ensure you initialize the lists if IsPostBack is false. Then, the ASP.NET Viewstate will take care of it all for you and keep all the selected values.

Answer (score 0):

First of all do not redirect the user when its not required.

Secondly use RequiredFieldValidator for your Fields. It will prevent the postback when your users forget to input any value.

And thirdly, if you are Binding dropdownlists programetically, do that in

```
If(!IsPostBack)
{
   //Your ddl initialization here
}
```

This will ensure you get the selected values from DropDownLists

Answer (score 0):

agree with use RequiredFieldValidator. and, controls should hold their values if view state is on for the control (check properties).